# Convert Inputstream to Multipart Form in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, java-11, resteasy

I integrated SendGrid's Inbound Parse into my app. 
My resource:

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Uni<Response> consumeMail(@Context HttpHeaders headers,
                                     InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        log.info("Received new email");
        log.info("Request headers");
        try (inputStream) {
            var bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
            log.infof("Data length %s", bytes.length);
            var mail = mailProcessService.saveMail(bytes);
            // How to convert bytes array to EmailFormData?
        }
        return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.accepted().build());
    }
```

Then I don't know how to convert InputStream to multipart/form-data object in Quarkus.
Is it possible?

```
public class EmailFormData {
    @FormParam("dkim")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String dkim;

    @FormParam("email")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String email;

    @FormParam("to")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String to;

    @FormParam("from")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String from;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an `InputStream`?

Comment: `InputStream` can convert full requests from The Inbound Parse WebHook to a byte array. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Just declare `EmailFormData` in place of `InputStream` and let Quarkus do all the works doesn't work?

Comment: Is there any solution that I can receive both `EmailFormData` and `InputStream`? Because in case of Quarkus parsed failed, I want to save raw mail to DB